# linked List: C: does not store the values I am looking for

Tags: c, scope, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have the following code:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct stringData {
    char *s;
    struct stringData *next;
} Node;

Node *createNode(char *s) {
    Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->s = s;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}


void insert(Node **link, Node *newNode) {
    newNode->next = *link;
    *link = newNode;
}

void printList(Node *head) {
    while (head != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", head->s);
        head = head->next;
    }
}


void listFilesRecursively(char *path, char *suffix);


int main()
{
    // Directory path to list files
    char path[100];
    char suffix[100];

    // Suffix Band Sentinel-2 of Type B02_10m.tif

    // Input path from user
    printf("Enter path to list files: ");
    scanf("%s", path);
    printf("Enter the bands ending: ");
    scanf("%s", suffix);

    listFilesRecursively(path, suffix);

    return 0;
}

int string_ends_with(const char * str, const char * suffix)
{
    int str_len = strlen(str);
    int suffix_len = strlen(suffix);

    return 
        (str_len >= suffix_len) &&
        (0 == strcmp(str + (str_len-suffix_len), suffix));
}

/**
 * Lists all files and sub-directories recursively 
 * considering path as base path.
 */


void listFilesRecursively(char *basePath, char *suffix)
{
    char path[1000];
    struct dirent *dp;
    DIR *dir = opendir(basePath);
    //node_s *head, *first, *temp=0;
    //head = malloc(sizeof(node_s));
    Node *head = NULL;
    Node *tail = NULL;
    Node *n;


    // Unable to open directory stream
    if (!dir)
        return;

    while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {


        if (strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dp->d_name, "..") != 0)
        {
            //printf("%s\n", dp->d_name);

            // Construct new path from our base path
            strcpy(path, basePath);
            strcat(path, "/");
            strcat(path, dp->d_name);

            if (string_ends_with(path, suffix))
            {
                n = createNode(path);
                insert(&head, n);
                tail = n;   
                printf("%s\n", path);
            }
            listFilesRecursively(path, suffix);
        }
    }

    //printList(head);

    closedir(dir);
}
```

And the aim is to store the values of a recursive search in a directory, in a linked list. I created the structure for a Node for string Data that points to the next element of the linked list. I also added some functions to insert the new data and point to the next one. And finally I am able to print out the values of the linked list by invoking printLIst function. However when I deactivate line 109 where the printList function is called, the values printed in line 103 are the correct ones. If I comment the line 103, and call the printLIst function with the values stored in my linked list, then a list of files comes, with values that are completely different from the ones printed in line 103.

Is a sort of black magic in C? or why is this strange behaviour?

Comment: `newNode->s = s;` does __not__ make a copy of `s`!

Comment: If you can use POSIX features this could be useful: https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this statement

```
n = createNode(path);
```

you are storing a pointer to the same local array `path` in each node. See the definition of the function `createNode`.

```
Node *createNode(char *s) {
    Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->s = s;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}
```

So the program at least due to this mistake has undefined behavior.

You should make a copy of the passed string instead of just assigning a pointer to it to the data member `s`.